# Postgres drop table syntax error

Tags: sql, postgresql, heroku

Postgres 9.3.2 on heroku.

Pretty sure I'm just being an idiot, but I can't seem to figure out why my syntax is wrong.

```
db=> \dt
              List of relations
 Schema |    Name    | Type  |     Owner      
--------+------------+-------+----------------
 public | device     | table | admin
 public | post       | table | admin
 public | user       | table | admin
(3 rows)

// why does this fail?
db=> drop table user; 
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "user"
LINE 1: drop table user;

// does the right thing
db=> drop table error; 
ERROR:  table "error" does not exist
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`User` is a [reserved keyword](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html) in Postgres.  You'll have to put it in quotes if you want to refer to an *actual* table named *user*:

`DROP TABLE "user";`

Probably best to stay away from using reserved keywords as table names if you can help it.  It usually ends up creating weird problems down the road.  `Users` might be a better name for a table.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same error. My database name was very unique and not a `reserved keyword`. Still needed to wrap the database name with quotation marks

`"<database_name>"`

Also for those that might forget always add a semicolon `;` at the end of the statement, I always forget.